# undefined method `article_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

this error is occuring and i have no idea why, thanks, 
undefined method `article_path' for #<#:0x000001029cb960>

edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Editing <%= @article.name %></h1>

<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %> <-- ????something here?
    <p>
        <%= f.label :name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>


<% end %>
```

articles model

```
class MediaController < ApplicationController


    def index
        @articles = Articles.all
    end

    def show
        @article = Articles.find(params[:id])
    end

    def edit
        @article = Articles.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @article.find(params[:id])
        article_params = params.require(:article).permit(:name, :description, :location)
        @article.update(article_params)
        redirect_to @article
    end

end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :media
  patch "events/:id" => "media#update", as: "update_medium"
```

Comment: Your model should be singular `Article` not plural `Articles`.  Fixing this in your controller might resolve this issue.

Comment: why your model name is media and object name is article..?this is because you are using different names for model and routes why don't you use rails naming convention..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your routes to

```
patch "articles/:id" => "media#update", as: "update_medium"
```

And model name to singular like :

```
@articles = Article.all
```